# Передача данных при уничтожении дочернего Activity

Tags: android

Существует необходимость передать в родительское Activity информацию из дочернего независимо от того как оно закрывается: нажатие на в интерфейсе, нажатие на кнопку назад, удаление Activity при нехватке памяти.

Код не дает нужного результата

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("some_data", "some_value");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

При закрытии Activity кнопкой назад в родительском Activity получаю Intent data = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в SharedPreferences сохранять данные, в методе onResume родительского Activity проверять есть ли что, или startActivityForResult().

Comment: передавать данные между активити через SharedPreferences , примерно то же самое , что слать письма через почту соседу по площадке , то есть общатся вы конечно будете , но можно и попроще и побыстрее

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно в вызывающей активити переопределить метод обратного вызова `onActivityResult()` , который получит интент , помещенный через `SetResult()` в вызванной активити /
 Для того , чтобы интент был отправлен в случае всякого закрытия вызванной активити , нужно в ней переопределить метод `finish()` ,который вызывается при всех действиях по зарытию активити и раньше `onPause()` , через которую `setResult()` уже не успевает отправить интент .
Единственное , что при аварийном закрытии может и он не сработать , но здесь уже 100% надежного способа нет.

вызывающее активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button mButton;
final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent;

  intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch (requestCode) {
     case REQUEST_CODE:
       int number = data.getIntExtra("number", 1);
  }
}
```

Вызываемая активити:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {


  @override
  public void finish(){
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("number", 3);
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  super.finish();
 }
}
```

Comment: Это самый правильный вариант, остальные ответы не совсем корректны

Answer (score 1):

А в дочерней активити переопределяете onActivityResult() ?

Comment: зачем переопределять onActivityResult в вызываемом activity? мне нужно получить данные в вызывающем Activity.
Может быть я что то не понимаю ::unknown::

Comment: написал в ДОЧЕРНЕМ, а не в вызываемом. А вообще, код обеих активити за вызов и возврат значений постить нужно. На будущее.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("some_data", "some_value");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

Comment: onStop не помогает - пробовал

Answer (score 0):

один из вариантов это

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
            intent.putExtra(...);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
    }
}
```

Но, я считаю немного не правильно это, а если я случайно нажал и мне нужно вернуться назад без последствий ?