# Передать данные в другое Активити

Tags: java, android

Нужно передавать данные `arraylist <integer>`  из `SettingsActivity` в `MainActivity`, но не по нажатию кнопки, а когда я нажимаю кнопку "назад" на эмуляторе. Соответственно, в `MainActivity` нужно принимать их. В каких методах это делать? `onRestart()` `onPause()`?

**MainActivity.class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

CustomAdapter myAdapter;




public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = data.getIntegerArrayListExtra("numbers");
    ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList_1 = data.getIntegerArrayListExtra("progresses");
    for (int i=0;i<integerArrayList.size();i++){
    myAdapter.progresses[myAdapter.numbers[integerArrayList.get(i)]]=integerArrayList_1.get(i);
    }
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**SettingsActivity:**

```
public void setClick (View view){
    numSetList.add(Integer.parseInt(editRow.getText().toString()));
    progSetList.add(Integer.parseInt(editPercent.getText().toString()));

    Integer [] numSetArr = numSetList.toArray(new Integer[numSetList.size()]);
    Integer [] progSetArr = progSetList.toArray(new Integer[progSetList.size()]);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),numSetArr,progSetArr);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSettings);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public void finish(){
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("numbers",numSetList);
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("progresses",progSetList);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
super.finish();

}
```

**Адаптер :**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Integer [] numbers;
Integer [] progresses;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, Integer[] numbers, Integer[] progresses) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.numbers = numbers;
    this.progresses = progresses;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvText)).setText(numbers[position].toString());
    ((ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)).setProgress(progresses[position]);
    return view;
}
```

На данный момент в `SetingsActivity` все работает правильно, но в `MainActivity` данные почему то не передаются (или не принимаются). Или может не обновляются данные адаптера?

Comment: смотрите этот ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416808/177345

Answer (score 2):

Используйте startActivityForResult вместо startActivity, это обработает за вас возвращение данных на предыдущую активити. Хороший пример [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult)

Comment: Использовал, отредактировал вопрос. Результата нет. Как проверить, передаются ли данные? или может, проблема в приеме

Comment: В классе mainActivity также надо переопределить метод onActivityResult, вот туда ответ и будет приходить

Comment: onActivityResult? переопределен.

Comment: Да, верно, извиняюсь, не заметил. А вы проверяли этот переопределенный метод finish() вообще орабатывается?

Comment: Проверил. Не отрабатывает. В чем может быть дело? Вообще,этого метода finish в списке overriden methods не могу найти

Comment: Переопределяй метод onPause например, он вызывается когда активити пропадает из виду, или onStop. Вообще советую почитать о жизненном цикле активити, и выбрать для себя какой Метод переопределить

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23892/discussion-between-werder-and-600).